# How to use bundled fonts in Mapbox iOS SDK?

Tags: ios, mapbox-ios

I'm using Mapbox iOS SDK 6.2.0-beta.2 and it [doesn't load the custom fonts we serve on our tile server](https://github.com/mapbox/mapbox-gl-native-ios/issues/450). In order to expedite our iOS 14 preparation I'm trying to make Mapbox use locally available fonts, but I can't find a good example. The [docs](https://docs.mapbox.com/ios/api/maps/6.2.0-beta.2/customizing-fonts.html) are a bit vague to me. Can you help me make Mapbox use local fonts instead of the fonts specified in the style JSON?

Answer (score 0):

According to Mapbox docs on [Customizing Fonts](https://docs.mapbox.com/ios/api/maps/6.2.0-beta.2/customizing-fonts.html):

> If the symbol layer does not specify an available font that contains the required glyphs, then the map tries to find a matching font in the `MGLIdeographicFontFamilyName` Info.plist key.

From Mapbox references on [`MGLIdeographicFontFamilyName`](https://docs.mapbox.com/ios/api/maps/6.2.0-beta.2/infoplist-keys.html#mglideographicfontfamilyname):

> This key specifies a fallback for all style layers in all map views and map snapshots.

> This key can either be set to a single string or an array of strings, which the map tries to apply in order from most preferred to least preferred. Each string can be a family name (for example, “PingFang TC”), display name (“PingFang TC Ultralight”), or PostScript name (“PingFangTC-Ultralight”).

So if you need to use a locally bundled font for your map style, put a string (or array of strings in order of preference) of your [locally embedded font](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/text_display_and_fonts/adding_a_custom_font_to_your_app) name, family or PostScript name in `MGLIdeographicFontFamilyName` in your project's `Info.plist` file.